# Event when iframe content load complete

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload-event

How to get event when iframe content load complete.
I have tried below option but event is coming before content load

```
document.getElementById("iFrameId").onload = function(event) {
    console.log("iframe loaded before content loaded);
};
```

Comment: Is the iframe on the same origin as the parent window?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - onload should fire regardless, shouldn't it?

Comment: @JaromandaX onload yes, but hooking into `DOMContentLoaded` is a different matter

Comment: I must be reading a different question then :p

Comment: @JamesThorpe, it is on the same origin

Comment: What makes you think the event is occurring before the contents are loaded? It might be before the content is rendered.

Comment: As I can see in-network tab that API calls are going after load event is occurred